# Translate special character ½

Tags: python, unicode

I am reading a source that contains the special character `½`. How do I convert this to `1/2`? The character is part of a sentence and I still need to be able to use this string "normally". I am reading webpage sources, so I'm not sure that I will always know the encoding??

**Edit:** I have tried looking at other answers, but they don't work for me. They always seem to start with something like:

```
s= u'£10"
```

but I get an error already there: "no encoding declared". But do I know what encoding I'm getting in, or does that not matter? Do I just pick one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dietrich beat me to the punch, but here is some more detail about setting the encoding for your source file:

Because you want to search for a literal unicode ½, you need to be able to write it in your source file. Unfortunately, the Python interpreter chokes on *any* unicode input, unless you specify the encoding of that source file with a comment in the first couple of lines, like so:

```
 # coding=utf8
 # ... do stuff here ...
```

This assumes your editor is saving the file as UTF-8. If it's using a different encoding specify that instead. See [PEP-0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more details.

Once you've specified the encoding you should be able to write something this in your code:

```
text = text.replace('½', '1/2')
```

#### Encoding of the webpage

Depending on how you are downloading the page, you probably don't need to worry about this at all, most HTTP libraries handle choosing the encoding for you automatically.

Comment: I tried that and got a new error: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd. I am using Putty, and did set the translation to utf8 (although, does the editor setting matter if I'm not actually printing the character?)

Comment: My mistake, changing the u'½' unicode literal to just '½' should make it work.

Comment: Cool, it works now. Thanks. Also, Putty wasn't saving the utf8 encoding setting, so I went with # coding= ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe). I'll now work on getting putty to use the utf8 encoding.  Have I got this right: the encoding of the editor matters, even if I'm not printing? So, if the code works for me, it may not work for someone who opens it in their editor, with a different setup? And, if it's running on some external server via Django, then I'd need to find out what their setup is?

Comment: The encoding of the editor only matters insofar as it writes the correct bytes to the file. Most editors will detect the file-encoding and save the file properly these days so it's unlikely to be something you need to worry about.

Also, with Putty the trick is to save the settings to a profile (possibly saving over the default profile) and reconnect.

Answer (score 5):

This is really two questions.

**#1. To interpret ½:**  Use the `unicodedata` module.  You can ask for the numeric value of the character or you can normalize using a canonical normalization form it and parse it yourself.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.numeric(u'½')
0.5
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', u'½')
'1⁄2'
```

**#2. Encoding problems:** If you're working with the terminal, make sure Python knows the terminal encoding.  If you're writing source files, make sure Python knows the file encoding.  You can't just "pick" an encoding to set for Python, you must inform Python about the encoding that your terminal / text editor *already uses.*

Python lets you set the encoding of files with Vim/Emacs style comments.  Put a comment at the top of the file like this if you use Vim:

```
# coding=UTF-8
```

Or this, if you use Emacs:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

If you use neither Vim nor Emacs, then it doesn't matter which one.  Obviously, if you don't use UTF-8 you should substitute the encoding you actually use.  (UTF-8 is the only encoding I can recommend.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `codecs` to read your file? [[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html)]

```
import codecs
fileObj = codecs.open( "someFile", "r", "utf-8" )
u = fileObj.read() # Returns a Unicode string from the UTF-8 bytes in the file
```

You can check the whole guide [here](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html).

Also a good ref: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode

Comment: And then I can see if it's ½? Would I need the unicode translation of that? What I want is to see whether my sentences start with a number, including ½. But, I'm not even allowed to write ½ in my program without getting an error.